# How to maintain CREATE VIEW script in postgres rather than VIEW DEFINITION

Tags: postgresql, view

I am using Postgres Version 9.1 and am having some trouble reviewing past `VIEWS` that I have created.

Once I create a `VIEW`, Postgres jumbles up the `CREATE VIEW` text so it is very unreadable.

For instance, I might create a simple `VIEW` as:

```
create view some_view as
select *
from some_table
where some_column = 'some_value';
```

This then turns into something way more complicated as:

```
select [all columns...]
from some_table
where (((some_column = 'some_value')));
```

Now, this is a simple example - however when you get into multiple `JOINS` and `WHERE` clauses or `SUBQUERIES` it gets nearly impossible to read so as to edit the `VIEW` at a later date.

(The exact location the `VIEWS` are stored is in `information_schema.pg_views` if anybody cares to look.)

For that reason I save my `CREATE VIEW` scripts as a separate `.sql` file, however this can get taxing and is obviously has the liability of not being sync'd with the current `VIEW` in the Postgres Database (if you update the `VIEW` but don't update the `.sql` file for instance).

It would be MUCH more simple if the plain text of the `CREATE VIEW` was saved.

When I create a `FUNCTION`, it saves the script entirely as is with all white-space, etc.

This makes it very simple, at a later date, to review it and see if it needs to be fixed up or spot possible errors.

So my question is if there is some place in the Postgres database where the actual plain-text is saved of the `CREATE VIEW` statement for later review/editing.

Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track to do this in SQL scripts. Just never ever manually change the database, always deploy changes through your scripts (which of course should be stored in a versioning system like Git or Subversion). Tools like Liquibase help you with all that

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I recently implemented a versioning system with Git and this is working and if this is the right way to go, then so be it. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found, the correct answer is to:

a) Maintain your SQL Scripts in separate files
b) Have a proper versioning system (Git, etc.)
c) Deploy from the versioning system

Done Deal.